# Angular JS, construct a dynamic path request

Tags: angularjs, json, request

I want to construct the follow request

http://www.example-server.com/{{param-1}}/{{param-2}}/example

This is the actual request

```
$http({
            method:'POST',
            url:"http://www.example-server.com/server/request/example",
            data : {
              phone: $scope.phone,
              company: $scope.company,
              contract: '1',
              privacy: '1',
              email: $scope.email
            },
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
```

And this is the request that I want to construct

```
    $http({
            method:'POST',
            url:"http://www.example-server.com/{{param-1}}/{{param-2}}/example",
            data : {
              phone: $scope.phone,
              company: $scope.company,
              contract: '1',
              privacy: '1',
              email: $scope.email
            },
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
```

Comment: Angular notation {{}} is not used like that in JS. That's used on your html files. Seems like you might be missing something in your post thats preventing you from dynamically constructing your URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 var1 = "path1";
 var2 = "path2";

 $http({
        method:'POST',
        url:"http://www.example-server.com/" + var1 + "/" + var2 + "/example",
        data : {
          phone: $scope.phone,
          company: $scope.company,
          contract: '1',
          privacy: '1',
          email: $scope.email
        },
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    })
```